# Setting action on a button created dynamically

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am working on Sencha Touch 2 application where some buttons are dynamically created depending upon the number of videos returned from JSON.

I have created the buttons but how to set action on those buttons. I mean how to identify, which button was pressed.

Normally in config we have:

```
 config:
       {
            layout: 'vbox',
            fullscreen: true,

            listeners:
                [
                   {
                        delegate: '#button1',
                        event: 'tap',
                        fn: 'itemClicked'
                   },
                ],
```

This action will be set for 'button1' only. So how do I set action of 10 buttons for example. and in my action how can I identify which button was pressed.

Thanks,

Comment: You want to do the same action for 10 buttons or different?

Comment: How did you create the buttons ? Is it a list, a custom data item or something else? Instead of using `listener` config for each button, using `controller` is good way to choose to handle events. Can you post the code that generates those buttons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys,

I am adding these buttons to a panel. I solved it using this code:

```
var b_Panel = Ext.getCmp('bottompanel');
for(var i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
    var aButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button',
     {
        text:'button'+i,
        margin:8,
        id:'button'+i,
        itemId:i,
        listeners:
         {
           tap: function()
             {
                console.log("Item ID is: "+this.getItemId());
             }
         }
     });

b_Panel.add(aButton);
```

}

Thanks,